# Have the NFC Normalization semantics changed between Java 6 and 7?

Tags: java, unicode, java-7, normalization, unicode-normalization

The unicode character `U+FA8E   CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-FA8E` is a compatibility character mapped to `U+641C   [CJK Unified Ideographs]`. In Java 6 `NFC` normalization leaves it `U+FA8E`, while in Java 7 it does decompose it to `U+641C`?

When running this small snippet:

```
String fancyChar = "\uFA8E";
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(fancyChar, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
System.out.printf("%04x == %04x\n", (int)(fancyChar.charAt(0)), (int)(normalized.charAt(0)));
System.out.println(fancyChar.equals(normalized));
```

In Java 6 (latest versions of both Sun/Oracle and OpenJDK):

```
fa8e == fa8e
true
```

In Java 7  (latest versions of both Sun/Oracle and OpenJDK):

```
fa8e == 641c
false
```

**So my question is, why has this changed?**

Reading the [UNICODE NORMALIZATION FORMS](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) it seems NFC should not decompose characters with compatibility mapping?

But the fact that both Oracle and OpenJDK have switched this for Java 7 makes me wonder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character U+FA8E has *canonical* mapping to U+641C. The authoritative reference on this is the [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) file in the Unicode Character Database. Thus, the correct NFC form of U+FA8E is U+641C.

So this is apparently a bug fix. It seems to affect other characters in the same group, too.

Comment: i've been reading more, and it looks like I might have been confused by the "COMPATIBILITY" in the name.